# Buttons and Line height Doctype difference

Tags: html, css, button, doctype

I have the following html/css (i use inline for demonstration purposes):

```
<div style="background-color:#e00; height:30px;">
    <div style="float:left;line-height:30px;">
        <button style="height:20px;line-height:normal;">Button 1</button>
    </div>

    <div style="float:right;line-height:30px;">
        <button style="height:20px;line-height:normal;">Button 2</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

if you run the code under HTML5 doctype, the buttons will be vertically aligned in the middle(what i expected).

However, if you run it under HTML4 Transitional doctype, the buttons will be floated to the top. A fix for this is to add a &nbps;(or any text) after the button. Any idea why this happens?

Answer (score 0):

Are you going to use one layout on two different doctype pages? If not, then whats the issue?

However, here is some reading about the differences: http://www.w3.org/TR/html5-diff/